# Debug st.executeUpdate(sql);

Tags: debugging, derby

I'm just wondering about debugging this Java code in NetBeans(using Derby) :

private boolean SimpanTabelProduk() throws SQLException 
    {

...

try {
           ...
            st.executeUpdate(sql);

```
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert...");                                
        tersimpan = true;                      
    }
```

afer the line 
st.executeUpdate(sql);

debugger didn't process the rest of lines, so tersimpan is always false. But it shows message "Insert".

If I change the code like this(tersimpan is integer) :

tersimpan = st.executeUpdate(sql);

tersimpan is still 0, but I can see in NetBeans Watches debugging window that st.executeUpdate(sql) return value 1. It seems like Derby(or Java) ignored tersimpan variable, and ignored lines after   :

st.executeUpdate(sql);

There is no mistakes in my sql statement, data can be saved in Derby correctly. I have tried many times. Could anybody explain this phenomenon ?

Comment: is your tersimpan variable an integer or a boolean. Your code shows that you are setting it to 'true', but your question talks about 1 and 0 and about the return type of executeUpdate, which returns an integer. Probably people could give you a lot more help if you showed **all** your code, not just a few oddly-formatted snippets.

Comment: I'm sorry, you didn't read my question carefully. If tersimpan is boolean, then of course the initialization is : tersimpan = false; and if tersimpan is integer then of course the initialization is : tersimpan = 0; and then the code tersimpan = st.executeUpdate(sql); should return 1. But it still remain 0. By the the way, I have already understand my problem. It because of race condition like Yohan Weerasinghe problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431807/unable-to-update-the-table-where-pimary-key-is-located. And it was still a problem without solution.

Comment: I can handle it with catching the error code : if (e.getErrorCode() == 30000) { ...., but it doesn't make me satisfied with the race condition of derby...

Comment: And thanks for your attention Brian.

Comment: I'm happy you solved your problem!